# How to install Apache Tomcat on centOS 

Tags: apache, tomcat, java, yum

How to install Apache Tomcat on centOS.
Java is not installed on my server. JDK or JRE (version 1.5 or 1.6) Which one I need to install?.Please help

Comment: This is not appropriate for SO.  It belongs on http://Serverfault.com or another SE site.

Comment: @ Fredrik   I was wrong. That is root access

Answer (score 7):

Download JDK for Linux (like this): jdk-6u20-linux-i586-rpm.bin (for Java 6 update 20 for linux!).

After your download, execute theses commands:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd Desktop/
[root@localhost Desktop]# chmod +x  jdk-6u20-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

execute the JDK install:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# ./jdk-6u20-linux-i586-rpm.bin

[root@centos ~]# yum -y remove java-1.4.2-gcj-compat

[root@localhost Desktop]# vi /etc/profile
```

After line -- # Functions and aliases go in /etc/bashrc put this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Attention for java version! And directories

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# source /etc/profile

[root@localhost Desktop]# java -version
```

Installing tomcat 6: donwload tomcat at http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi, Binary Distributions – Core, file .tar.gz. And execute:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# tar zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.26.tar.gz

[root@localhost Desktop]# mv apache-tomcat-6.0.26/ /usr/local/tomcat

[root@localhost Desktop]# rm -f apache-tomcat-6.0.26.tar.gz

[root@localhost Desktop]# vi /etc/profile
```

Add after Java's line:

```
export TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib
```

Execute this:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# source /etc/profile

[root@localhost Desktop]# /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```